# How do I re-activate my Twitter account using the same email address?

Tags: twitter, account-management

I deleted my Twitter account, and now I can't create a new one with the same email address!

How do I get a new Twitter account with the same email address?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this recently, and I thought this would be a good question to answer here.

One way that worked for me was to create an new twitter account with a *different* email address, and then once that account was active I changed the email address on the account back to the old email address.

Useful tip for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Twitter's support page explicitly states this:

> If you wish to use your username or
>   email address with a future account,
>   be sure to change them in your
>   Settings page before you deactivate
>   your account.

Comment: Yes, I (foolishly) explicitly ignored that advice.  Fortunately I found a work around.

Comment: This isn't true anymore after five years. Today (2015) I have failed on creating new Twitter account using previously used e-mail, even though I changed it prior to old account deactivation, exactly as instructed in mentioned text.

Comment: What was your workaround, @JohnWeldon? —Oh, it appears you added your workaround as a separate answer. Thanks.